# Why do this 're.search' return 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to produce a web crawler to download HTML from a [website](http://%22http://example.webscraping.com/view/Afghanistan-1%22), but I don't know the `re` model very well, and have gotten stuck.

```
import urllib2
def download(url):
    print("Downloading: " + url)
    try:
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print("Download error: ", e.reason)
        html = None
    return html

FIELD = ('area', 'population', 'iso', 'country', 'capital', 'continent', 'tld', 'currency_code', 'currency_name', 'phone',
    'postal_code_format', 'postal_code_regex', 'languages', 'neighhbours')

import re
def re_scraper(html):
    results = {}
    for field in FIELD:
        results[field] = re.search('<tr id="places_%s__row">.*?<td class="w2p_fw">(.*?)</td>' % field, html).group()
    return results

import time
NUM_ITERATIONS = 1000
html = download("http://example.webscraping.com/view/Afghanistan-1")
for name, scraper in [('Regular expressions', re_scraper), ('BeautifulSoup', bs_scraper), ('Lxml', lxml_scraper)]:
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        if scraper == re_scraper:
            re.purge()
        result = scraper(html)
        assert (result['area'] == '647,500 square kilometres')
    end = time.time()
print('%s: %.2f seconds' % (name, end - start))
```

The error message:

```
File "E:/���/Projects/new.py", line 20, in re_scraper
    results[field] = re.search('<tr id="places_%s__row">.*?<td class="w2p_fw">(.*?)</td>' % field, html).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

The HTML is:

```
<tr id="places_area__row"><td class="w2p_fl"><label for="places_area" id="places_area__label">Area: </label></td><td class="w2p_fw">647,500 square kilometres</td>
```

I have tested the code and finding HTML and regex is no problem. The problem may be with `field` or `FIELD`. I think their type my be causing this bug, but how can I fix it?

Comment: why you use .group()

Comment: where did you call `re_scraper `, and where did you define `FIELD`? Both of them in the same files?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first query, so what i said may not clear. i use .group() to match (.*?) in  re.search. @Enix: And  I think calling of re_scraper and FIELD would be right, so i didn't put up the code, but i add them now.